# SSL is not working for Route 53 domain on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've deployed my Django app on AWS Elastic Beanstalk Linux instance. I've used Route 53 to point it to a custom domain from GoDaddy.

Now I want to use SSL for my website.
I don't want to use Load Balancers for SSL since I'm using only 1 instance and it's costly to pay $18/month.
So what I did is using Let's Encrypt SSL by adding **00_apache_ssl.config** file in my **.ebextensions** folder.

I've followed [this](https://www.mattbutton.com/2019/02/12/enabling-https-on-elastic-beanstalk-without-a-load-balancer/) tutorial to use the SSL. My SSL is working perfectly for Elastic Beanstalk URL. But the problem is it's not working for my custom domain.

My EB Url is showing secure connection while it's custom domain is showing Insecure connection.
What I'm lacking of? Do I need to do some changes in Route 53 Record sets as well?

Thank you.

**Edit 1:** My custom domain is showing the Let's encrypt certificate as Invalid Certificate.

Comment: Where do you store the certificate for custom domain?

Comment: @MatusDubrava I haven't generated it yet. Do I need to generate the certificate for custom domain following that tutorial as well?

Comment: It would be rather lengthy discussion about how public key cryptography works but long story short - no certificate = no encryption. Device that is "serving" HTTPS needs to have access to private key to establish secure connection so yes, you need to have a certificate for that domain and you can't just generate it if you plan to serve your content publicly. You need to obtain (buy) such certificate from a trusted certificate authority. I would say that you can obtain if for free from AWS ACM but that doesn't hold since such certificate can only be used with LoadBalancer and/or CloudFront.

Comment: @MatusDubrava Okay I get it. So if I purchase SSL from GoDaddy or somewhere else, can you please explain me or provide me some resources about how I can use it? I've searched it over the internet but couldn't find the suitable resources. Thanks.

Comment: I am sorry. I don't know exact resource for your particular web server but you should find it rather easily by googling for `apache ssl configuration`. The actual configuration may require some linux admin skills though.

Comment: @MatusDubrava okay. I'll look for `apache ssl config`. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

According to your tutorial, you have got an SSL certificate for your `elasticbeanstalk` domain, not your custom domain.

If you want to access your website via your custom domain with https (for e.g https://my-cust-doamin.com), you have to get a certificate for your domain.

You can obtain SSL certificate from any provider who sells SSL certificates.

Note: You can also get a wildcard certificate(*.my-cust-domain.com), which could be used with any of your sub domains.

reference:
https://rickchristianson.wordpress.com/2013/10/31/getting-a-django-app-to-use-https-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk/

Comment: Yes. @Matus have told me the same in the comments section. Can you provide me some resources for the same? Thanks.

Comment: can you share the contents of the  `00_apache_ssl.config` file . i think you just need to add the new certificate files and update the references in this file.